# Bathroom Window Repair

Tags: bathroom

Was hoping to get some advice. we had our windows replaced and the shower window now needs to be repaired as it was outside the scope of work for the installers. I am a home improvement novice and was looking for some guidance. See the attached picture. [image]

Comment: How is it malfunctioning?

Comment: When you say repaired are you talking about fixing the trim? I can't see anything other than that wrong with the photo.